# Access COM server Methods using C#

Tags: c#, python, com-server

I wrote a com server implementation in python. The code is as follows.

```
import pythoncom
    class PythonUtilities:    
    _public_methods_ = [ 'SplitString' ] 
    _reg_progid_ = "PythonDemos.Utilities"
    _reg_clsid_ = pythoncom.CreateGuid()
    print _reg_clsid_
    def SplitString(self, val, item=None):
        import string
        if item != None: item = str(item)
        return string.split(str(val), item)
    if __name__=='__main__':        
    print 'Registering Com Server'
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonUtilities)
```

Im really new to this and i want to learn how to access the python function in dotnet c#.
 can someone help me or provide some guidelines. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try pythonnet?